# MongoDB. Prisma. Добавить аргумент в существующую коллекцию

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, prisma

У меня есть модель

```
model Compares {
    id          String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    id1         String
    id2         String  
    slug1       String
    slug2       String 
    userId      String @db.ObjectId
}
```

Всё работает отлично. Мне нужно добавить аргумент `visits`:

```
model Compares {
    id          String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    id1         String
    id2         String  
    slug1       String
    slug2       String
    visits      String 
    userId      String @db.ObjectId
}
```

после `npx prisma generate` я всё равно получаю ошибку при вызове `prisma.compares.create`: `Unknown argument "visits". Available options are marked with ?.` И из доступных он мне показывает  `?   id?: String`

Я не могу понять, как мне добавить аргумент? Я полностью удалял коллекцию и создавал заново и всё равно ошибка. Я думал, может зарезервированное название, но я пробовал и другие, всё равно не помогает.